# Query results not ordered despite WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am storing posts from all users in table. I want to retrieve post from all users the user is following.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  userid int,
  time timestamp,
  id uuid,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, time)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

I have the data about who all user follows in another table

```
CREATE TABLE follow (
  userid int,
  who_follow_me set<int>,
  who_i_follow set<int>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((userid))
)
```

I am making query like

```
select * from posts where userid in(1,2,3,4....n);
```

2 questions:

1. why I still get data in random order, though  CLUSTERING ORDER BY is specified in posts. ?
2. Is model correct to satisfy the query optimally (user can have n number of followers)?

I am using Cassandra 2.0.10.

Answer (score 3):

"why I still get data in random order, though CLUSTERING ORDER BY is specified in posts?"

This is because `ORDER BY` only works for rows within a particular partitioning key.  So in your case, if you wanted to see all of the posts for a specific user like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid=1;
```

That return your results ordered by `time`, as all of the rows within the `userid=1` partitioning key would be clustered by it.

"Is model correct to satisfy the query optimally (user can have n number of followers)?"

It will work, as long as you don't care about getting the results ordered by timestamp.  To be able to query posts for all users ordered by time, you would need to come up with a different partitioning key.  Without knowing too much about your application, you could use a column like `GROUP` (for instance) and partition on that.

So let's say that you evenly assign all of your users to eight groups: A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H.  Let's say your table design changed like this:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  group text,
  userid int,
  time timestamp,
  id uuid,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY (group, time, userid)
)WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

You could then query all posts for all users for group B like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE group='B';
```

That would give you all of the posts for all of the users in group B, ordered by time.  So basically, for your query to order the posts appropriately by time, you need to partition your post data on something other than userid.

**EDIT**:

```
PRIMARY KEY (userid, follows)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

That's not going to work.  In fact, that should produce the following error:

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column follows"

And even if you did add `follows` to your `CLUSTERING ORDER` clause, you would see this:

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Only clustering key columns can be defined in CLUSTERING ORDER directive"

The `CLUSTERING ORDER` clause can only be used on the clustering column(s), which in this case, is only the `follows` column.  Alter your PRIMARY KEY definition to cluster on `follows` (ASC) and `created` (DESC).  I have tested this, and inserted some sample data, and can see that this query works:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid=2 AND follows=1;

 userid | follows | created                  | id
--------+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:27:00-0600 | 559cda12-8fe7-45d3-9a61-7ddd2119fcda
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:26:00-0600 | 64b390ba-a323-4c71-baa8-e247a8bc9cdf
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:24:00-0600 | 1b325b66-8ae5-4a2e-a33d-ee9b5ad464b4

(3 rows)
```

Although, if you want to query by just `userid` you can see posts from all of your followers.  But in that case, the posts will only be ordered *within each followerid*, like this:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid=2;

 userid | follows | created                  | id
--------+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------
      2 |       0 | 2015-01-25 13:28:00-0600 | 94da27d0-e91f-4c1f-88f2-5a4bbc4a0096
      2 |       0 | 2015-01-25 13:23:00-0600 | 798053d3-f1c4-4c1d-a79d-d0faff10a5fb
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:27:00-0600 | 559cda12-8fe7-45d3-9a61-7ddd2119fcda
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:26:00-0600 | 64b390ba-a323-4c71-baa8-e247a8bc9cdf
      2 |       1 | 2015-01-25 13:24:00-0600 | 1b325b66-8ae5-4a2e-a33d-ee9b5ad464b4

(5 rows)
```

Comment: this answer definitely gave some better direction, but i wanted to get all post from all users whom i am following in descending order of time. I will provide my new schema below

Answer (score 1):

This is my new schema,

```
CREATE TABLE posts(id uuid, 
userid int,
follows int,
created timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY (userid, follows)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created DESC);
```

Here userid represents who posted it and follows represents userid for his one of the follower. Say user x follows 10 other people , i am making 10+1 inserts. Definitely there is too much data duplication. However now its easier to get timeline for one of the user with following query

```
select * from posts where follows=?
```