# Apache Cassandra table not sorting by name or title correctly

Tags: cassandra, datastax, database, nosql

I have the following Apache Cassandra Table working.

```
CREATE TABLE user_songs (
    member_id int,
    song_id int,
    title text,
    timestamp timeuuid,
    album_id int,
    album_title text,
    artist_names set<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((member_id, song_id), title)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (title ASC)
CREATE INDEX user_songs_member_id_idx ON music.user_songs (member_id);
```

When I try to do a `select * FROM user_songs WHERE member_id = 1;` I thought the Clustering Order by title would have given me a sorted ASC of the return - but it doesn't

Two questions:

- Is there something with the table in terms of ordering or PK?
- Do I need more tables for my needs in order to have a sorted title by member_id.

Note - my Cassandra queries for this table are:

- Find all songs with member_id
- Remove a song from memeber_id given song_id

Hence why the PK is composite

**UPDATE**
It is simialr to: [Query results not ordered despite WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853410/query-results-not-ordered-despite-with-clustering-order-by)

However one of the suggestion in the comments is to put `member_id,song_id,title` as primary instead of the composite that I currently have. When I do that It seems that I cannot delete with only song_id and member_id which is the data that I get for deleting (hence title is missing when deleting)

Comment: The clustering order applies with rows sharing the same partition key.  Since your partition key is 'member_id, song_id', the data returned will be sorted in title ascending order within the result set where the rows share the same member_id and song_id, but not with respect to other rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query results not ordered despite WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853410/query-results-not-ordered-despite-with-clustering-order-by)

Comment: I'd also recommend changing your primary key to 'PRIMARY KEY (member_id, song_id, title)'.   This way you don't need the secondary index .   You could also consider swapping the ordering of 'song_id' and 'title' so you can have data sorted for a member_id by title.

Comment: @AndyTolbert I tried that before (for the recommended primary key) however when deleting I will need the title to be passed where as (in a RDBMS mind frame) would be easier to pass song_id/member_id since that is unique.